# url encode in asp3

Tags: encoding, utf-8, asp-classic

how can I set the url encode in asp3
similar to the [asp.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h10z5byc.aspx) code

```
Public Shared Function UrlEncode ( _
    str As String, _
    e As Encoding _
) As String
```

how can I pass the encoding type?

Comment: Are you asking about [Server.URLEncode(string)](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_urlencode.asp)?

Comment: yes. or similar function

Comment: @Eduardo post this as answer, IMO it's the correct one as well. :)

Comment: I think the asker is familiar with the Server.URLEncode(string) method. this question is about setting different encoding for the url string.

Answer (score 3):

Simply call UrlEncode and as the second parameter specify the encoding

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h10z5byc.aspx

This same overload is supported in .net 3 so you should be good.

Comment: what happens, what call specifically is failing? post code please

Answer (score 1):

Use Server.URLEncode(string) for classic asp.

> <%
>   response.write(Server.URLEncode("http://www.myurl.com?param1=value1&param2=value2"))
>   %>

Answer (score 0):

You could also UriEncode but this function is only pressent in javascript but you can switch language in asp-classic

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" RUNAT="Server">
  function fnencodeURIComponent(n)
  {
    return  encodeURIComponent(n)
  }

  function fndecodeURIComponent(n)
  {
    return decodeURIComponent(n)
  }

</SCRIPT>
<% 'normal asp
    url = fnencodeURIComponent(myString)
%>
```

Comment: there is no encoding type in your ASP.net example either

Comment: So what"type" is desired?  I think it's normally it's converted to hexadecimal equivalent.